# Bitcoinjs-lib help with deterministc wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoinjs, deterministic-wallets

i'm learning about bitcoin, and bitcoinjs-lib (https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib)

I created a dummy wallet on coinomi using this mnemonic ('eight better wealth display father cave suffer game sign health fit exchange noble tunnel poet remember owner letter submit illness cage calm dry noble')

and i'm trying to generate a Deterministic wallet with it.

Here is my code

> const bip39 = require('bip39')
>   const bip32 = require('bip32')
>   const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
>   const network = bitcoin.networks.bitcoin;
>   function getAddress (node) {
>   return bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: node.publicKey, network}).address
>   }
>   const mnemonic = 'eight better wealth display father cave suffer game
>   sign health fit exchange noble tunnel poet remember owner letter
>   submit illness cage calm dry noble'
>   console.log('Testing mnemonic: ',bip39.validateMnemonic(mnemonic))
>   const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)
>   const root = bip32.fromSeed(seed)
>   console.log("m/0'/0/1 ->",getAddress(root.derivePath("m/0'/0/1")));
>   console.log("m/0'/0/2 ->",getAddress(root.derivePath("m/0'/0/2")));

.

and this is the output that i got

.

> Testing mnemonic: true
>   m/0'/0/1 -> 17tdSW83Vjw23TdQsmZDtBAupan9WiGGd5
>   m/0'/0/2 -> 17bYSjEXwZxMgVkRRt9pJgDgExiX8Xht3b

Then I go to (https://www.coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html) to test if my results are correct, and it isn't, could someone help me with this please. How to fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is working. Go to https://www.coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html and make sure to enter the following:

**BIP39 Recovery Phrase** : `eight better wealth display father cave suffer game sign health fit exchange noble tunnel poet remember owner letter submit illness cage calm dry noble`

**Coin** : Bitcoin

**BIP32 Derivation Path** (In BIP32 Tab): `m/0'/0`

Result:

**Derived Addresses**

```
m/0'/0/0`   169zFhK1WTuxfhgY6bmzE9zP1godCfZr2V
m/0'/0/1    17tdSW83Vjw23TdQsmZDtBAupan9WiGGd5
m/0'/0/2    17bYSjEXwZxMgVkRRt9pJgDgExiX8Xht3b
```

Comment: hmm thanks, i was using the site wrongly. but just another question, I can get the public key from this code `root.derivePath("m/0'/0/0").publicKey.toString('hex')` and I get "02db987662b3f1a84c8465ac710de96106ba65aef63d0967e605b802d5fd2579e5" with is correct, but with private key, that doens't work, do you know how I can display my private key for path 0/0? (I resolved it by myself, the solution was to use root.derivePath("m/0'/0/0").toWIF()